# Why am I getting C2064 and c 2056 ERROR in C++ in such situation

Tags: c++, c++17, std, filesystemwatcher

I'm doing a little file watcher in C++, but after some refactoring I got stuck with some problem. Mainly I understand what's the problem. I call a function which is actually not a function, but I cannot find such thing. All answers say that there is some name which is called as a function.

Here is my header:

```cpp
#ifndef FILEWATCHER_H
#define FILEWATCHER_H
#include <unordered_map>
#include <filesystem>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

class FileWatcher
{
    size_t currentNumberOfFiles = 0;
    fs::path pathToWatch;
    std::unordered_map<fs::path, fs::file_time_type> pathsMap;
    std::string currentTime();
public:
    FileWatcher(fs::path path);
    void start();
};
    
#endif
```

And the .cpp file:

```cpp
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
#include "FileWatcher.h"
#include "Event.h"

std::string FileWatcher::currentTime()
{
    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::time_t nowTime = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);
    std::string currentSystemTime = std::ctime(&nowTime);
    return currentSystemTime;
}

FileWatcher::FileWatcher(fs::path pathToWatch)
{
    this->pathToWatch = pathToWatch;
    //create a map with last modification of a given file in the directory
    for (auto& file : fs::directory_iterator(this->pathToWatch))
    {
        pathsMap.emplace(file.path(), fs::last_write_time(file));
    }
}

void FileWatcher::start()
{
    while (true)
    {
        currentNumberOfFiles = std::distance(fs::directory_iterator(pathToWatch), fs::directory_iterator());

        for (std::unordered_map<fs::path, fs::file_time_type>::iterator it = pathsMap.begin(); it != pathsMap.end(); )
        {
            if (!fs::exists(it->first))
            {   
                if (currentNumberOfFiles < pathsMap.size())
                {
                    //std::cout << "File was erased" << std::endl;
                    it = pathsMap.erase(it);
                    //FileType fileType = ( ? FileType::FILE : FileType::DIRECTORY);
                    std::string time = this->currentTime();
                    Event event(EventType::DELETED, FileType::FILE, it->first, time);
                    event.printEvent();
                }
                else
                {
                    //std::cout << "Renamed" << std::endl;
                    it = pathsMap.erase(it);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                it++;
            }
        }
        
        for (auto& file : fs::directory_iterator(pathToWatch))
        {
            if (!pathsMap.count(file.path()))
            {
                //std::cout << "File has been created" << std::endl;
                pathsMap.emplace(file.path(), fs::last_write_time(file));
            }
            else
            {
                if (pathsMap.at(file.path()) != fs::last_write_time(file))
                {
                    //std::cout << "File has been modified" << std::endl;
                    pathsMap.at(file.path()) = fs::last_write_time(file);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the error list:

[image: Error list image]

1st error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Column  Category    Source  Suppression State
Error   C2056   illegal expression  ProgrammingAssignment   C:\VisualStudio2019\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xhash 130 44      Build
```

2nd error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Column  Category    Source  Suppression State
Error   C2064   term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments ProgrammingAssignment   C:\VisualStudio2019\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xhash 131 53      Build
```

This is the place error list refer to in the `filesystem` library.

```
template <class _Hasher, class _Kty>
_INLINE_VAR constexpr bool _Nothrow_hash = noexcept(
    static_cast<size_t>(_STD declval<const _Hasher&>()(_STD declval<const _Kty&>())));
```

This is the error output:

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: ProgrammingAssignment, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>FileWatcher.cpp
1>C:\VisualStudio2019\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xhash(131,53): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
1>C:\VisualStudio2019\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xhash(155): message : see reference to variable template 'const bool _Nothrow_hash<std::hash<std::filesystem::path>,std::filesystem::path>' being compiled
1>C:\VisualStudio2019\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xhash(155): message : while compiling class template member function 'size_t std::_Uhash_compare<_Kty,_Hasher,_Keyeq>::operator ()<_Kty>(const _Keyty &) noexcept(<expr>) const'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=std::filesystem::path,
1>            _Hasher=std::hash<std::filesystem::path>,
1>            _Keyeq=std::equal_to<std::filesystem::path>,
1>            _Keyty=std::filesystem::path
1>        ]
1>C:\VisualStudio2019\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xhash(1218): message : see reference to variable template 'const bool _Nothrow_hash<std::_Umap_traits<std::filesystem::path,std::chrono::time_point<std::filesystem::_File_time_clock,std::chrono::duration<__int64,std::ratio<1,10000000> > >,std::_Uhash_compare<std::filesystem::path,std::hash<std::filesystem::path>,std::equal_to<std::filesystem::path> >,std::allocator<std::pair<std::filesystem::path const ,std::chrono::time_point<std::filesystem::_File_time_clock,std::chrono::duration<__int64,std::ratio<1,10000000> > > > >,0>,std::filesystem::path>' being compiled
1>C:\VisualStudio2019\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xhash(1218): message : while compiling class template member function 'std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>> std::_Hash<std::_Umap_traits<_Kty,std::chrono::time_point<std::filesystem::_File_time_clock,std::chrono::duration<std::chrono::system_clock::rep,std::chrono::system_clock::period>>,std::_Uhash_compare<_Kty,_Hasher,_Keyeq>,_Alloc,false>>::erase<std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>>,0>(std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>>) noexcept(<expr>)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=std::pair<const std::filesystem::path,std::filesystem::file_time_type>,
1>            _Kty=std::filesystem::path,
1>            _Hasher=std::hash<std::filesystem::path>,
1>            _Keyeq=std::equal_to<std::filesystem::path>,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const std::filesystem::path,std::filesystem::file_time_type>>
1>        ]
1>C:\VisualStudio2019\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xhash(130,44): error C2056: illegal expression
1>Done building project "ProgrammingAssignment.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Does your compiler emit only error codes, or is there a description along with the error number?  Please edit your post with the error  message, verbatim, along with description.

Comment: Also, please edit your code with some kind of marker indicating which statement the compiler is referring to.

Comment: Also, get rid of the line: `#pragma warning(disable : 4996)`.  Warnings are helpful.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, this is the problem, the compiler refers to library file. But ok, I will edit the question.

Comment: There are a plethora of library files in existence.  You'll have to be more specific.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, removed #pragma, it didn't help.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, I use standard C++17 ```filesystem``` header.

Comment: Is there any way you can highlight the error text to the clipboard (copy) and paste into your question as text?  Images don't scale well and are difficult to read.  Links will decay or be blocked by firewalls.

Comment: If your compiler error message says the error line is on 42, you'll have to indicate, in your posted code, which statement is line 42.  That's what comments can be used for.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, again, what is shown in the error list as line and column is a coordinates at the header file. Not the one written by me.

Comment: @CuriousPanCake OK, but without seeing what THAT code looks like, we can't really help you. Obviously, your code is calling into library code. If we knew *which* library code was failing, maybe we might know which line in YOUR code is failing. Since you have not indicated WHICH line that actually is

Comment: @CuriousPanCake: The "Error" window only shows useless summaries. The full error message is in the "output" window. Please copy the full text from the "output" window :(

Comment: FYI, if I place an extra `')'` in my GUI code, MS Visual Studio 2017 will list 30 errors in different files, including library files.  You may have to try commenting out code until the code compiles with zero errors.

Comment: Have you looked at [Compiler Error C2064](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2064?view=msvc-160) and [Compiler errors C2000 through C2099](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-errors-c2001-through-c2099) for the other?

Answer (score 3):

The error messages are very difficult to read, but it basically boils down to a missing implementation of `std::hash<std::filesystem::path>`.

[`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) uses hashes to order its elements.  By default, it uses a specialization of [`std::hash`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) on the map's `key_type`.  However, the standard library does not provide a specialization of `std::hash` for `std::filesystem::path`, hence the errors.

So, if you want to use `std::filesystem::path` as the `key_type` of `std::unordered_map`, you have to either:

- provide your own specialization of `std::hash<std::filesystem::path>`, eg:

```cpp
template <>
class std::hash<fs::path>
{
public:
    size_t operator()(const fs::path &path) const
    {
        return ... a hash of path ...;
    }
};

class FileWatcher
{
    ...
    std::unordered_map<fs::path, fs::file_time_type> pathsMap;
    ...
};
```

- implement a custom `class`/`struct` with an `operator()` that takes a `std::filesystem::path` as input and returns a unique value as output.  Then you can explicitly state that type in the `std::unordered_map`'s `Hash` template parameter, eg:

```cpp
struct MyPathHash
{
    size_t operator()(const fs::path &path) const
    {
        return ... a hash of path ...;
    }
};

class FileWatcher
{
    ...
    std::unordered_map<fs::path, fs::file_time_type, MyPathHash> pathsMap;
    ...
};
```

Otherwise, use `std::map` instead.  It uses `operator<` to order its elements, and `std::filesytem::path` has its own [`operator<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/operator_cmp) implemented, eg:

```cpp
...
#include <map>

class FileWatcher
{
    ...
    std::map<fs::path, fs::file_time_type> pathsMap;
    ...
};
```

Comment: So I should provide a definition for ```operator<``` for the ```fs::path``` and use it with ```std::map```?

Comment: You don't need to provide a custom `operator<` for `fs::path`, [it already has one](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/operator_cmp).

Comment: Thank you very much, it solved my problem.